# Typo correction library in Java

Tags: library, java, nlp

I need a **java** library which has functions to predict a the right word for a wrong input. for example:

If I input "`lool`" it should give me suggestion like "`look`".

To be precise, I'm expecting a Java equivalent to a library like [T9js](https://github.com/talyssonoc/jsT9), which is a Javascript library which does what I expect.

Few more requirements on what I need is a typo library for english, open source, no size limitations.

Comment: Do you mean correction? For English?

Comment: Do you need open source? Gratis? Reusable? Modifiable? Do you have a budget?

Comment: Do you have a size limitation? (for instance is a 100 MB JAR OK?)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul yes I need a library for english, open source, no size limitations.

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information, comments get deleted. Thanks!